# Electrical conductivity of quartz glass at a certain temperature

Tags: materials, electrically-conductive

What is the state of the material, from the electrical conductivity point, of quartz glass at 1100 K temperature, given the value of conductivity at 330 K temperature which is 1.5 × 10<sup>-12</sup> S/m and 8.7 × 10<sup>-14</sup> S/m at 300 K temperature?

I can't figure out which formula is supposed to be used in this case. On the other hand, I searched the properties for quartz glass and it seems to withstand temperatures upto 837 K but I cannot understand what this means from an electrical conductivity point.  Should it lose its insulating properties and become a conductor?

Comment: The conductivity rapidly changes with melting points dependent on added conductive materials or contaminants, so that is not easily predicted.  E.g. lithium, copper, gold, lead

Comment: Yes, glass conducts surprisingly well at very high temperature and poorly at low temperature. AFAIR conduction is mainly ionic at high temperatures.

Comment: There is the classic physics demonstration where you strip the cable from a mains plug, wrap the wires around a glass rod (separated by a centimetre or two), and plug it in. Nothing happens. You then heat the rod with a blowlamp, after reaching yellow-hot things start to progress extremely quickly! Best done with a blast screen and an umbrella (it will be raining glass that has bounced off the ceiling)...possibly also a torch so that you can find the breakers you just popped. I always enjoyed demos like that.